# cross compiling release files

Tags: cross-compilation, makefile

In my Makefile I have this to crosscompile for my rpi0w, rpi02w and rpi4:

```
release_files: clean
    @mkdir build
    @echo building for linux/amd64 ...
    @CGO_ENABLED=1 GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux $(MAKE) build
    @openssl dgst -sha256 "build/bettercap" > "build/bettercap-amd64.sha256"
    @zip -j "build/bettercap-$(VERSION)-amd64.zip" build/bettercap build/bettercap-amd64.sha256 > /dev/null
    @rm -rf build/bettercap build/bettercap-amd64.sha256
    @echo building for linux/armhf ...
    @CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc GOARM=6 GOARCH=arm GOOS=linux $(MAKE) build
    @openssl dgst -sha256 "build/bettercap" > "build/bettercap-armhf.sha256"
    @zip -j "build/bettercap-$(VERSION)-armhf.zip" build/bettercap build/bettercap-armhf.sha256 > /dev/null
    @rm -rf build/pwngrid build/bettercap-armhf.sha256
    @echo building for linux/aarch64 ...
    @CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc GOARCH=arm64 GOOS=linux $(MAKE) build
    @openssl dgst -sha256 "build/bettercap" > "build/bettercap-aarch64.sha256"
    @zip -j "build/bettercap-$(VERSION)-aarch64.zip" build/bettercap build/bettercap-aarch64.sha256 > /dev/null
    @rm -rf build/pwngrid build/bettercap-aarch64.sha256
    @ls -la build
```

The amd64 building part works, as I'm on an AMD64 laptop. But the armhf and aarch64 parts fail. I have the cross-compilers (arm-linux-gnueabihf and aarch64-linux-gnu) installed. But I get the following errors. But I cannot find any way to compiling them or installing them accordingly.

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetfilter_queue: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lnfnetlink: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm most likely to be searching for the wrong keywords on Google.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're facing with `-lnetfilter_queue` and `-lnfnetlink` suggest missing libraries for your cross-compilation targets. Here are some potential solutions:

**1. Installing the libraries:**

- Make sure the libraries `libnetfilter_queue` and `libnfnetlink` are installed for your target architecture, likely in a package named `libnfnetlink-dev` or similar. On Debian-based systems, you can use `sudo apt install libnfnetlink-dev`.
- Check the output of `pkg-config --list-all | grep netfilter` to see available libraries and their paths.
- Verify the library search path used by your cross-compiler. The error message seems to suggest a mismatch between the compiler and linker paths. Look for options like `-I` and `-L` passed to the compiler and linker in your Makefile or cross-compilation toolchain configuration.

**2. Specifying library paths:**

- Explicitly tell the linker where to find the libraries. Use the `-L` flag with the directory containing the `libnetfilter_queue.so` and `libnfnetlink.so` files for your target architecture.
- Modify your Makefile to pass the correct library paths using `LDFLAGS` for the armhf and aarch64 builds.

**3. Alternative libraries:**

- Consider using alternatives like `libnetfilter_conntrack` which might be available on your target system and achieve similar functionality.

**4. Troubleshooting and searching:**

- Double-check the spelling of the library names in your Makefile.
- Search for the specific error messages you're getting online, focusing on your cross-compilation setup and target architecture.
- Use tools like `nm` to analyze the compiled binary and identify missing symbols to pinpoint the specific library dependencies.

Remember to adjust the commands and package names based on your specific Linux distribution and cross-compilation environment. For better search results, include details like your Linux distro, cross-compiler versions, and exact error messages when searching online.

I hope this helps! Feel free to share any additional information or specific error messages you encounter for further assistance.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. I have been trying to add armhf and arm64 architecture to my AMD64 laptop. 
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf`

But for some reason the apt sources keep getting ignored. So I cannot install the packages that way.I'll try some more, perhaps. And now I know why, there are no armhf/arm64 jammy packages.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libnetfilter-queue-dev:armhf libnetfilter-queue-dev:armhf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnfnetlink-dev:armhf
Suggested packages:
  libnetfilter-queue-doc:armhf
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libnetfilter-queue-dev libnfnetlink-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnetfilter-queue-dev:armhf libnfnetlink-dev:armhf

Comment: It seems libnfnetlink-dev and libnetfilter-queue-dev are not quite cross compatible.